# Stuck on loading template

Tags: meteor

Hey I have a system where a logged in user can be in a "battle" and as soon as they are, I want the user to be locked on a given template, until the battle is done.

I have

```
#
# Currently active battle
#
Meteor.publish 'activeBattle', ->
  character = Characters.findOne(userId: this.userId)
  if this.userId and character
    return Battles.find({active: true, $or: [{characterOneId: character._id}, {characterTwoId: character._id}]})
  else
    return
```

and in my iron-router

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
  waitOn: [
    Meteor.subscribe('activeBattle')
  ]

...

redirectToActiveBattle = (pause) ->
  battle = Battles.findOne(active: true)
  if battle and Meteor.userId()
    throwError('You have a battle in progress.')
    Router.go('combat', {_id: battle._id})
    pause()

...

Router.onBeforeAction(redirectToActiveBattle, except: ['login', 'logout', 'signup', 'combat'])
```

This works when the user is logged in and has a character, but if not, the page is stuck on the loading template, instead of displaying the login screen

Comment: Try `return []` instead of just `return` in your `publish`'s `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should use `this.ready();` instead of an empty return if you don't want to return anything in a publication. So the right way to do the publication could be:

```
Meteor.publish 'activeBattle', ->
  character = Characters.findOne(userId: this.userId)
  if this.userId and character
    return Battles.find({active: true, $or: [{characterOneId: character._id}, {characterTwoId: character._id}]})
  this.ready()
```